# Button width cut off in Safari

Tags: css

I have an issue with only one button in Safari. It is cut off, but as soon as I hover over it, it takes full width like it should. Did anyone encounter this issue? I will copy the css for button and link the image.

CSS:

```
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#f14f27), to(#ff7b5a));
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #f14f27 0%, #ff7b5a 
    color: #FFFFFF;
    min-width: 140px;
    width: auto;

display: inline-block;
font-weight: normal;
line-height: 1.25;
text-align: center;
white-space: nowrap;
vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
font-size: 1rem;
border-radius: 0.25rem;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;

font-size: 15px;
padding: 11px;
border-radius: 6px;
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried width 100% rather than auto?

Comment: @billy.farroll width: 100% will take too much space, its not really a good solution

Comment: Oh right, maybe try max-width: 140px; with the width: 100% this way it won't go bigger than the 140px;

Comment: Give button float: left; try this.

Comment: This could be caused by a lot of things, but as far as I tested it, the button styles are not the problem, can you provde a link or a test-enviroment like jsfiddle / codepen?

Comment: can you provide fiddle or any other demo link?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, `display:flex` on the parent div was creating an issue with `display:block/inline-block` on the button. I just set `display:flex` on buttons and it solved the issue